# how to find inequality of $z$ from inequality of $y$ and $z-y$

Tags: inequality

This question is about inequalities and although it seems simple I just can't do it even though I have tried several times. If $0<y<1$ what is the range of $z$ if $0<z-y<1$?

Comment: Add $y$ to all sides?

Comment: You can add numbers to any inequality and multiply by positive numbers. Here $0<z-y<1$ implies $y<z<1+y$. Now use what you know about $y$ to figure out what $z$ can be.